# Handle ranking in a document mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a model with a rank. 
I want to update all rank when i delete one element , add or update .

Here is my model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema

var consignemodeSchema = new Shema({
    consigne: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    mode: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    rank: {
        type: number,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Update documents](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html) link to update all rank. 
Here, you can add following line into your callback for each element update, delete or add operation.

```
var conditions = {}
  , update = { $inc: { rank: 1 }}
  , options = { multi: true };

Model.update(conditions, update, options, callback);
```

Comment: Can i do it with save ?

Comment: var query = {
        consigne: req.params.consigne,
        mode : req.params.mode
    },
    update = { $inc: {rank: req.body.rang}},
    options = {mutli : true}
    ConsigneMode.update(query, update, options, callback)
    
    function callback(err, num) {
        if (err)
            return(res.status(400).send(err))
    }

Comment: You can do it with Save, Update and Remove. The above JS code snippet looks good.